# python script not running with web.py

Tags: python, web.py

I am new to Python and am trying to run a very simple Python script on a web page, using the tutorial on [web.py](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/tutorial).  When I installed web.py through the terminal it said it installed successfully, but when I try to run hello.py I get the following error messages (screenshot and text below), and nothing opens on my localhost.  [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4YI4.png)

```
----------------------
CODE FROM WEB.PY
----------------------

import web

urls = (
  '/', 'hello')

app = web.application(urls, globals())

class hello:
    def GET(self):
        return 'Hello, web!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

---

### ERROR MESSAGE

> The above is a description of an error in a Python program, formatted
>        for a Web browser because the 'cgitb' module was enabled.  In case you
>        are not reading this in a Web browser, here is the original traceback:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "hello.py", line 1, in
>   <module>
>       import web   File "/Users/swanstro/Desktop/web/**init**.py", line 14, in <module>
>       import utils, db, net, wsgi, http, webapi, httpserver, debugerror   File "/Users/swanstro/Desktop/web/wsgi.py", line 8, in <module>
>       import http   File "/Users/swanstro/Desktop/web/http.py", line 16, in <module>
>       import net, utils, webapi as web   File "/Users/swanstro/Desktop/web/webapi.py", line 31, in <module>
>       import sys, cgi, Cookie, pprint, urlparse, urllib   File "/Users/swanstro/Desktop/cgi.py", line 22, in <module>
>       form = cgi.FieldStorage() AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'FieldStorage'

Any help would be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: You should copy and paste your traceback into your question.  Also include the code example so that someone might be able to spot what is wrong

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a file named `cgi.py` (/Users/swanstro/Desktop/cgi.py) that is conflicting with the Python standard library `cgi` module when you try to `import cgi`. Try renaming `cgi.py` to something else.